# Getting start with Zend PHP framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've been working with PHP for couple of months now.  Learning online, copy paste some code from online tutorials etc.
One major problem now is there are many unclean/unstable/unsecure/bad practice php tutorials out there.

I decided it's time for me to go to the next step.  I heard about the current most popular PHP framework is Zend.  How should I start with that? What softwares do I need to install? Any recommendation for Tutorials/book/video training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with a Framework is a good idea. That will help you to improve the structure of your code and you'll find that it is easier to make bigger projects.

If you want to start with the Zend Framework, I recommend you the [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html) which is a good tutorial to get started with it and have a first overview of the different patterns used in the framework.

Answer (score 3):

While Zend Framework 1.x is a very powerful tool (and I use it frequently) I would **not** recommend it as a framework for learning **best practice**.

If you're truly interested in learning the best practices and standards for PHP development then you're much better off working with the latest Zend Framework 2 builds, which will actually teach you **current** PHP 5.3 standards like proper namespacing and autoloading.

Here's a link to the [ZF2 Github repository](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2) (where you can get almost current builds).
Here's a link to the [Symfony framework](http://symfony.com/) which also uses the latest OOP best practices.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to uloBasEl's suggestion, I'd add the [rest of the tutorials on the Zend Framework site as well](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/manual.html). The manual, as well as the API, is very well written and maintained.

Also, the MVC (Model-View-Control) pattern is excellent for most web applications. I would suggest its use in both PHP and ASP.Net.